# How to read/write text card by line?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I try to read/write by line ID from/to txt file store in SD card using Auduino Uno. But I don't sucsess.
Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
if (myFile) {
 while (myFile.available()) {
  String line = myFile.readStringUntil('\n');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you still need help with this one, but here goes.

### **First suggestion - changing the login.txt**

Instead of using br tags, try inserting "\r\n" between your IDs. For example, if you are creating your login.txt by making a PHP+SQL database query, and writing results into a file, replace the br in your code with "\r\n". Or, if you are able to open and edit the login.txt, do that, and replace each of the br with a new line.

All you have to do then is read each of the lines in your file, one by one.

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

int CS_PIN = 10;
char logfile[] = {"login.txt"};

File file;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  initializeSD();

  openFile(logfile);
  while(file.available()) {
    // print the lines to serial monitor
    Serial.println(readLine());
  }
  closeFile();
}
void loop() {
}

void initializeSD() {
  Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
  pinMode(CS_PIN, OUTPUT);

  if (SD.begin()) {
    Serial.println("SD card is ready to use.");
  } else {
    Serial.println("SD card initialization failed");
    return;
  }
}

void closeFile() {
  if (file) {
    file.close();
    Serial.println("File closed");
  }
}

int openFile(char filename[]) {
  file = SD.open(filename);
  if (file) {
    Serial.println("File opened with success!");
    return 1;
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error opening file...");
    return 0;
  }
}

String readLine() {
  String received = "";
  char ch;
  while (file.available()) {
    ch = file.read();
    if (ch == '\n') {
      return String(received);
    } else {
      received += ch;
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

This is a shortened, **untested**, and somewhat modified version of the code posted on this [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sS_oW81NweI) (see the video descripton for a link to the full code). Also, be sure to double check the wiring, so it's as shown in the video.

### **Second suggestion - changing the way the incoming chars are read**

If you are unable to change the structure of the login.txt file, and can only read it from an SD card, try this code in order to read from a file (modified version of the one in the first suggestion):

```
String readLine() {
  String received = "";
  char ch;
  while (file.available()) {
    ch = file.read();
    if (ch == '<') {            // Is the tag starting?
      return String(received);  // Return what you have so far (ID)
    } else if(ch == '>') {      // Is the tag ending?
      received = "";            // Empty the string, we don't need br
    } else {                    // Everything's OK, append to the string
      received += ch;
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```

Please note that both suggestions **will not** store the lines into separate variables. I suggest that you do what you want to do (print to serial, flash a LED, etc) with each of the lines in the file, **as you read them**.

Comment: this answer is great! you should get more upwotes..

Answer (score 0):

Please start with the **Arduino > Examples > SD > ReadWrite**:

```
/*
  SD card read/write

 This example shows how to read and write data to and from an SD card file
 The circuit:
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13
 ** CS - pin 4

 created   Nov 2010
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe

 This example code is in the public domain.

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

File myFile;

void setup()
{
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }


  Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  // On the Ethernet Shield, CS is pin 4. It's set as an output by default.
  // Note that even if it's not used as the CS pin, the hardware SS pin
  // (10 on most Arduino boards, 53 on the Mega) must be left as an output
  // or the SD library functions will not work.
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);

  if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("initialization done.");

  // open the file. note that only one file can be open at a time,
  // so you have to close this one before opening another.
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  // if the file opened okay, write to it:
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.print("Writing to test.txt...");
    myFile.println("testing 1, 2, 3.");
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
    Serial.println("done.");
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }

  // re-open the file for reading:
  myFile = SD.open("test.txt");
  if (myFile) {
    Serial.println("test.txt:");

    // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
    while (myFile.available()) {
      Serial.write(myFile.read());
    }
    // close the file:
    myFile.close();
  } else {
    // if the file didn't open, print an error:
    Serial.println("error opening test.txt");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // nothing happens after setup
}
```

The code should work. Make sure your pins are correctly connected.

Comment: Thanhs for your help, My pins connect correctly and I read successful as you show me. But I want read IN LINE.Exple I have a login.txt: 41001662<br>41001536<br>.....And I want read 41001662 into String data1, 41001536 into data2.......

Answer (score 0):

Answare by Tavinson is correct which is

```
if (myFile) {
 while (myFile.available()) {
  String line = myFile.readStringUntil('\n');
 }
}
```